# Elegant API versioning in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, versioning

At the moment I'm implementing versioning for our REST API in our Rails application. Is there a way this can be implemented so you only define new functionality in new versions? Say for example:

I have a Users controller and a Products controller. Products has stayed the same between V1 and V2, but Users has changed. It would be nice if we could set it up so that if I call for V2 of Products, my application knows it doesn't exist and simply uses the most recent controller version instead (in this case, V1). This would allow for us to not create a whole new set of controllers for every version; we'd only create new controllers for the specific functionality that has changed.

Below is a snippet from our Routes.rb, and admittedly I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
namespace :api do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) do
      resources :users
      resources :products
    end
    scope module: :v2, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 2) do
      resources :users
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used the same strategy for sometime and recently changed approaches-and admittedly I'm biased because I'm also one of the authors of our new approach with [VersionCake](https://github.com/bwillis/versioncake).

This approach is to only version our payloads or views, afterall views are the contract between the client and if there is a breaking contract change, then the version needs to change. In VersionCake, you can version your views like so:

```
app/views/products/show.v1.rabl
app/views/products/show.v2.rabl
app/views/users/show.v1.rabl
```

The specific feature that is important based on your question is that VersionCake will gracefully degrade to the latest supported version. Given the example above, a client requesting `users/1.json` for version 2 will receive the payload for `users/show.v1.rabl`.

All this being said, it would require adopting a new versioning approach, so it might not be the best answer, but I think it's an option worth considering.

Comment: It looks interesting, and may I ask that do you ever face the need to create a new controller since the old one has too many version-specific conditions? How to cache per version? Thanks.

Comment: I have developed several version branches in a controller, but nothing so egregious that we needed to create a new controller. We will try to force as much version specific logic into models methods and call them in the views to try and leave the controllers as dry as possible. As for caching, it depends what type you mean. If using page caching, you should probably use the version in the etag.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) already?

What I have done over the API's I have built is, when something changes for all of them (like authentication) I just get them all to inherit from a specific versioned api controller, as in `Api::V1::BaseController` and place the common behavior and controls in there.

Since changing the API usually also meant changing the representations, using a tool that generates the representations for your is also really important, there are many gems out there for this as:

- [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)
- [Roar](https://github.com/apotonick/roar)
- [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Our team is already using RABL, so ideally we'd like to reuse those views in Grape. I'm looking into Grape right now and once I have a working implementation I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) is designed to do.

In addition, you have the option of mounting your API in your routes.rb file or mapping it in config.ru, bypassing the Rails stack and greatly improving the performance of the API.